# Kotlin: Whats does "return@" mean?

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I'm using RxJava in one of my projects, I converted one of my classes to Kotlin using the Android Studio plugin and in one of map `flatMap` lambda (Func1 in java), intermediates returns looks like the following `@Func1`.

I have no idea what this means.

```
something.flatMap(Func1<ArticleCriteria, Observable<Pair<String, String>>> {
    val isTemporaryClone = it.isATemporaryClone
    val isTheOriginalToken = it.tokenIsOriginalHere

    if (isTemporaryClone) {
        if (!isTheOriginalToken) {
            return@Func1 paramsError("Token is always original for temp articles")
        }

        return@Func1 mJobRunner.doNotRun(DeleteArticleJob.TAG)
                            .doOnNext(deletePersonalActionById(articleId))
    }

    runArticleJobAsync(DeleteArticleJob.TAG, it)
})
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

In Kotlin, the [`return@label` syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels) is used for specifying which function among several nested ones this statement returns from.

It works with function literals (lambdas) and local functions. Non-labeled `return` statements return from the nearest (i.e. innermost) enclosing `fun` (ignoring lambdas). Consider this function:

```
fun foo(ints: List<Int>) {
    ints.forEach {
        if (it == 0) return
        print(it)
    }
}
```

<sup>Here, `return` will finish the execution of `foo`, not just the lambda.</sup>

But if you want to return from any other function (a lambda or an outer `fun`) you have to specify it as a label at `return` statement:

```
fun foo(ints: List<Int>) {
    ints.forEach {
        if (it == 0) return@forEach // implicit label for lambda passed to forEach
        print(it)
    }
}
```

```
fun foo(ints: List<Int>): List<String> {
    val result = ints.map f@{
        if (it == 0) return@f "zero" // return at named label
        if (it == -1) return emptyList() // return at foo
        "number $it" // expression returned from lambda
    }
    return result
}

foo(listOf(1, -1, 1)) // []
foo(listOf(1, 0, 1)) // ["number 1", "zero", "number 1"]
```

[Non-local return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) (i.e. return from outer functions) from a lambda is only supported for [local](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions) and [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) functions, because if a lambda is not inlined (or a function is placed inside an object), it is not guaranteed to be called only inside the enclosing function (e.g. it can be stored in a variable and called later), and the non-local return would make no sense in this case.

---

There is also a similar syntax for [qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html), which is used to reference receivers of outer scopes: `this@outer`.

Comment: Thanks! It would have been nice if the official Kotlin docs covered this in a little more detail with examples as you did here.

Answer (score 17):

`return@name` determinates for which closure `return` statement should be applied.

In Kotlin, you can call return from nested closure to finish outer closure. In Java it is not possible.

Usually, you can omit `@name`.

In your example, you can't omit it because `Func1` is used inside another function.

Comment: If the code is written inside a function body, `@Func1` cannot be omitted.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about under which conditions `@Func1` can be omitted? I tried to use the expression `something.flatMap(...)` in a top level declaration, but I got the "`return` is not allowed here" error.

Comment: Thank you! Both @hotkey and mklimek answers are right, hotkey's answer is just a bit more elaborate I upvote both and check hotkey's :)

Comment: Is it possible to use it for `when` (the switch-case equivalent on Kotlin)  ? Many times I want to break it when the indentation is too much...