# Implicit return from lambda in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

It seems that the last line of a lambda always returns that value even if you omit the `return` statement. Is this correct? Is it documented anywhere?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nums = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val numsPlusOne = nums.map { it -> 
        val r = it + 1
        r
    }
    // numsPlusOne = [2, 3, 4]
}
```

Comment: Just a helpful hint, you can shorten that to `val numsPlusOne = nums.map { it + 1 }` (because `it` is implied if not specified, and if `it + 1` is the last line, its result will be returned as @hotkey explained)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, if the last statement of a lambda is an expression, it is considered its return value.

Here's [what the reference says](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) (thanks [@KirillRakhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman)):

> We can explicitly return a value from the lambda using the [qualified return](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) syntax. Otherwise, the value of the last expression is implictly returned. Therefore, the two following snippets are equivalent:
>
> ```
> ints.filter {
>     val shouldFilter = it > 0 
>     shouldFilter
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> ints.filter {
>     val shouldFilter = it > 0 
>     return@filter shouldFilter
> }
> ```

The last statement semantics is also true for [`if` (that's why there's no ternary operator)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression), `when` and [`try`-`catch`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#try-is-an-expression) blocks, and these statements are expressions themselves:

```
val foo = if (bar) { 
    doSomething()
    baz 
} else { 
    doSomethingElse()
    qux 
}
```

<sup>See also: [examples for `when` and `try`-`catch`](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/rrdg9fn46rg3563uvigo8o2bp6/dvqkeha0alvsaqjvl6hppb1n90).</sup>

So, lambdas are consistent with the language constructs in this respect.

---

If you want to make an explicit `return` statement in a lambda, use the [`return@label` syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) (also, [another answer with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean)). Non-labeled `return`, on contrary, works with the nearest `fun` (ignoring lambdas) and thus can only occur in those lambdas which are [inlined](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns).

There was a [language proposal](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8695) to add special syntax for *emitting* a value from a code block, but it was rejected.

Comment: "if the last statement of a lambda is an expression" - I can't find a definitive source for definitions, but I think it's incorrect to call the "expression" a "statement". The Kotlin docs only say "the value of the last expression is implicitly returned". My understanding is that statements typically don't produce values and that an `expression` is not a type of `statement`

Comment: @mowwwalker Well, while this is arguable, in [the Kotlin grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#statements), one kind of a statement is an expression, which may be a dangling unused value or a function call whose return value is ignored.

Comment: Ah awesome that settles that then :)