# Convert GsonBuilder into Kotlin

Tags: java, android, gson, kotlin

Does anyone know how to convert this code into kotlin

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setLenient();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            if (json.getAsJsonPrimitive().isNumber()) {
                return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong() * 1000);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
return builder.create();
```

Then, i tried

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
builder.setLenient()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java,.........)
return builder.create()
```

..... i can't figured it out how to convert the code

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code line that you are asking about can be converted to the following Kotlin code:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, JsonDeserializer<Date> { 
    json, typeOfT, context ->
    if (json.getAsJsonPrimitive().isNumber())
        Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong * 1000) else
        null
})
```

First, Kotlin supports [SAM conversion of lambdas to Java interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions), but the syntax is different to Java. Then, returns inside lambdas have different meaning to that in Java, and should be replaced with [implicit returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620937/implicit-return-from-lambda-in-kotlin) or [labeled returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i already figured it out.. is it the correct way to do it, any expert can comment

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson? {
        val builder = GsonBuilder()
        builder.setLenient()
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, JsonDeserializer<Date> { json, typeOfT, context ->
            if (json.asJsonPrimitive.isNumber) {
                Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong * 1000)
            } else {
                null
            }
        })
        return builder.create()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().apply {
        setLenient()
        registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java,
                JsonDeserializer<Date> { json, typeOfT, context ->
                    if(json.asJsonPrimitive.isNumber) {
                        Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong * 1000)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                })
    }.create()
```