# How to use Kotlin fold function to convert an array into a map?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert an Array via fold into an indexed Map. Somehow IntelliJ flags that when I return the accumulator that it expects Unit. When I remove the return it complains that I require the datatype I originally wanted to return.

The code is as follows (Item is just a data class)

```
    constructor(vararg items: Item){
    val itemMap = items.fold(mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Item>>(), { acc, item ->
        if (acc.containsKey(item.state)) {
            acc[item.state]?.add(item)
        } else {
            acc.put(item.state, mutableListOf(item))
        }
        return acc
    })

}
```

Its a bit late here so I probably miss something very obvious. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `return`.

Comment: FWIW, you can also achieve this entire thing with `val itemMap = items.groupBy { it.state }`.

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth. This is a lot easier. I didn't know about the groupBy function.

Answer (score 13):

Use the qualified `return@fold` operator instead of `return`. In Kotlin, `return` without a qualifier means 'return from the innermost `fun` (ignoring lambdas)'.

```
val itemMap = items.fold(mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Item>>(), { acc, item ->
    if (acc.containsKey(item.state)) {
        acc[item.state]?.add(item)
    } else {
        acc.put(item.state, mutableListOf(item))
    }
    return@fold acc
})
```

See [Whats does “return@” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean), [Return at Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) in the language reference.

Or just use the [result expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620937/implicit-return-from-lambda-in-kotlin), omitting `return`:

```
val itemMap = items.fold(mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Item>>(), { acc, item ->
    if (acc.containsKey(item.state)) {
        acc[item.state]?.add(item)
    } else {
        acc.put(item.state, mutableListOf(item))
    }
    acc
})
```

Basically, this kind of fold is implemented in the standard library: see [`.groupBy { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html).