# Converting Thread/Runnable implementation from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I have an existing Java class `ThreadUtils` with a method `every` that looks like:

```
public class ThreadUtil {

    public static Thread every(int seconds, Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                r.run();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * seconds);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to convert it to Kotlin. I'm a bit hung up on the Runnable closure. This fails with a bad `return`:

```
fun every(seconds: Int, r: Runnable): Thread {
    val t = Thread({
        while (true) {
            r.run()
            try {
                Thread.sleep((1000 * seconds).toLong())
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                return // ERROR: This function must return a value of type Thread
            }
        }
    })
    t.start()
    return t
}
```

I also tried pulling the Runnable out just to help myself separate things, but this also fails the same way:

```
fun every(seconds: Int, r: Runnable): Thread {
    val internalRunnable = Runnable {
        while (true) {
            r.run()
            try {
                Thread.sleep((1000 * seconds).toLong())
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                return // ERROR: This function must return a value of type Thread
            }
        }
    }
    val t = Thread(internalRunnable)
    t.start()
    return t
}
```

How can I implement a `@FunctionalInterface` or similar-style closure/lambda that doesn't try to `return` *from the function* in which it's being defined?

Comment: I work everyday with some so-called smart people inventions (aka projects), and this makes my work as a dev a nightmare, you mix uneccesserly technologies and ruin your, and others life doing so. Why you can't use java? Isn't it look stupid, to have to tell the language, that you are returning from a Thread writing that return statement inside a Thread? Do you feel what is good and what is bad? Do you have aesthetic sense when creating something? Progress is not when you just do another random thing, progres is when you feel it is right thing to do. Making more trouble isn't progress at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Kotlin, `return` statements inside lambdas work differently from those in Java. If you write just `return`, it means return from the innermost function declared with keyword `fun`, and it ignores lambdas -- in your code, it means 'return from `every`'.

To return from a lambda, use qualified `return@label`-- in your case, it's `return@Thread` (and `return@Runnable` for the second example), like in this simplified snippet:

```
for (i in 1..4) {
    Thread { 
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            return@Thread
        println("Thread $i")
    }.run()
}
```

[<sup>(runnable demo of this code)</sup>](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/kinaskevque6t5fastp6rsp9on/q89g5c956chr78jfk1ln61uoaa)

Also, there is a [`thread { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html) function in `kotlin-stdlib` that you might find useful (and, similarly, the return statement for its lambda is `return@thread`).

You can find a more detailed explanation in the [language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean).

Comment: Ah great, I didn't realize the difference in the `return` behavior - thanks for pointing that out, and for the `thread { }` shortcut.

Comment: should be `.start()` instead of `.run()` to be started in a different thread.