# Using return inside a lambda?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

In the code below, I want to show my empty views if trips is empty and then return and avoid running the below code, but the compiler says "return is not allowed here".

```
mainRepo.fetchUpcomingTrips { trips ->
    if (trips.isEmpty()) {
        showEmptyViews()
        return
    }

    // run some code if it's not empty
}
```

Is there a way to return like that?

I know I can just put it in an if else block but I hate writing if else's, it's less understandable/readable in my opinion when there's a few more conditions.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Just use the qualified return syntax: `return@fetchUpcomingTrips`.

In Kotlin, `return` inside a lambda means return from the innermost nesting `fun` (ignoring lambdas), and it is not allowed in lambdas that are not [inlined](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html).

The `return@label` syntax is used to specify the scope to return from. You can use the name of the function the lambda is passed to (`fetchUpcomingTrips`) as the label:

```
mainRepo.fetchUpcomingTrips { trips ->
    if (trips.isEmpty()) {
        showEmptyViews()
        return@fetchUpcomingTrips 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Related:

- [**Return at labels**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) in the language reference
- [**Whats does “return@” mean?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean)

Comment: Why is return not allowed in a lambda though? I don't see why it would be explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @EmilS. A non-inlined lambda may be called not in-place but wrapped into an instance passed to some other function and then called, maybe even on a different thread. In that case, a non-qualified `return` (which means 'return from the nearest `fun`') couldn't work.

Answer (score 28):

You can also replace `{ trips ->` with `fun(trips) {` to form an [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) which can use `return` normally.

Comment: though you can't make such function `suspend`

Answer (score 8):

Plain `return` suggests that you return from the function. Since you can't return from the function inside a lambda, the compiler will complain. Instead, you want to return from the lambda, and you have to use a label:

```
mainRepo.fetchUpcomingTrips { trips ->
    if (trips.isEmpty()) {
        showEmptyViews()
        return@fetchUpcomingTrips
    }

    //run some code if it's not empty
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [Return to Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels):

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    println("begin foo")
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@{
        // local return, meaning this function execution will end
        // the forEach will continue to the next element in the loop
        if (it == 3) return@lit
        
        println("- $it")
    }
    println("done with explicit label")
}
```

[Playground demo here](https://pl.kotl.in/nf4g1J0Y-).

Answer (score 3):

The  returns allow us to return from an outer function. The most important use case is returning from a lambda expression

A return statement in an anonymous function will return from the anonymous function itself.

```
fun foo() {
    ints.forEach(fun(value: Int) {
        if (value == 0) return  // local return to the caller of the anonymous fun, i.e. the forEach loop
        print(value)
    })
}
```

When returning a value, the parser gives preference to the qualified return, i.e.

```
return@a 1
```

means "return 1 at label @a" and not "return a labeled expression (@a 1)".

**Return**  By default returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function.

**Break**  Terminates the nearest enclosing loop.

**Continue**  Proceeds to the next step of the nearest enclosing loop.

More details refer [Returns and Jumps,Break and Continue Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `return` might be

```
mainRepo.fetchUpcomingTrips { trips ->
            if (trips.isEmpty())
                showEmptyViews()
            else {
                //run some code if it's not empty
            }
        }
```