# Kotlin: Multiple returns inside a Lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have a function that catches recoverable exceptions and returns a fallback

```
private fun <T> safely(block: () -> T, fallback: T): T {
    return try {
        block()
    } catch(exc: SomeException) {
        // Log the exception/do some logic
        fallback
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add this to the public methods of my class e.g.

```
fun doSomething(): List<String> = safely({
    val list = mutableListOf<String>("Hello")
    fun someCheck1() = false // Some boolean value
    fun someCheck2() = true // Some boolean value
    do {
        if(someCheck2()) {
            return arrayListOf<String>("Hello", "World")
        }
    } while (someCheck1())
    return list
}, arrayListOf<String>())
```

However I get compiler errors `'return' is not allowed here`

Yet if I remove the `return` then my return in the loop no longer works and it gets highlighted in my IDE with warning `the expression is never used`

How can I maintain this type of return logic within a Lambda?

[Playground Example](https://pl.kotl.in/eoHoayGva)

Comment: Would using a when expression help ?

Comment: Not in this case I don't think. I've probably oversimplified the code for the sake of this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
fun doSomething(): List<String> = safely(
    {
        val list = mutableListOf<String>("Hello")
        fun someCheck1() = false // Some boolean value
        fun someCheck2() = true // Some boolean value
        do {
            if (someCheck2()) {
                return@safely arrayListOf<String>("Hello", "World")
            }
        } while (someCheck1())
        list
    }
, arrayListOf<String>())
```

For further reference, check [Using return inside a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348820/using-return-inside-a-lambda)

Or you can also extract your block into a separate function (i.e. `someCheckFunction(): List<String>`), and have `fun doSomething() = safely({ someCheckFunction() }, arrayListOf())`, but I guess you want to maintain lambda code like above.

Comment: Perfect thank you! for whatever reason I had tried `return@doSomething list` but not `return@safely list`

Answer (score 1):

`return arrayListOf<String>("Hello", "World")` here tries to return a value from `doSomething` function rather than from the lambda passed to `safely`. However, such return is non-local, since it tries to exit from the function that is not on the top of stack, and therefore it is prohibited.

Another option here is to make `safely` function **inline**:

```
inline fun <T> safely(block: () -> T, fallback: T): T { ... }
```

and then you'll be able to make a non-local return from `block` lambda function passed to it.

Comment: Nice i've not used `inline` before