# return false in anonymous lambda

Tags: kotlin

This is my code.

```kotlin
fun isJoined(user: User): Boolean {
    val member = requireNotNull(guild.getMember(user)) { return false }
    return joined.contains(member)
}
```

When member is null, is the funtion 'isJoined' returns false or just anonymous function returns false (so that member to be false)?
If anonymous function returns false, then how can I change my code to return the function 'isJoined'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, lambdas with a return automatically default to returning from the innermost function, which means that your entire function will return false. [Read here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348930/5923139). Also, the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) provides a more elegant way to write this:

```kotlin
val member = guild.getMember(user) ?: return false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your `isJoined()` function like this:

```
fun isJoined(user: User): Boolean =
    guild.getMember(user)?.let { joined.contains(it) } == true
```

It will do the following things:

- When `guid.GetMember()` returns a member, it calls `joined.contains(member)`, which will return a boolean. Comparing a boolean with `== true` is a noop, so the result of `contains(member)` is returned.
- When `guild.GetMember()` returns `null`, the `let` block is not called, and the expression becomes `null == true`, which returns `false`.

It's equivalent to this:

```
fun isJoined(user: User): Boolean {
    val nullableMember = guild.getMember(user)
    return if (nullableMember == null) false else joined.contains(nullableMember)
}
```