# Kotlin - Preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, preferences

I'm trying to add an onPreferenceClickListener within my SettingsFragment and if I do it like this:

```
signOutPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(object: Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
           override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
                    val signOutIntent = Intent(activity, SignInActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(signOutIntent)
                    return true
                }
            })
```

It works perfectly while giving a warning:

> Use property access syntax

While if I write it like this:

```
signOutPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                val signOutIntent = Intent(activity, SignInActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(signOutIntent)
                return true
            }
```

which should be the exactly the same thing and it's the best way to do it, I get a:

> The Boolean literal does not conform to the expected type Unit

on the `return true` statement.

What am I missing? Is the second way to do it different than the first? How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: remove the `return` keyword

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a lambda, the last statement automatically becomes the returned value unless it's return type is inferred as `Unit`. So simply remove `return`.

```
signOutPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
   val signOutIntent = Intent(activity, SignInActivity::class.java)
   startActivity(signOutIntent)
   true
}
```

The documentation says:

> A lambda expression is always surrounded by curly braces, parameter declarations in the full syntactic form go inside curly braces and have optional type annotations, the body goes after an -> sign. *If* the inferred return type of the lambda is not `Unit`, the **last (or possibly single) expression inside the lambda body is treated as the return value**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing this part, still gotta get my head around lambda expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `return@setOnPreferenceClickListener true`.

### Explanation

[Quoting from this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean):

> In Kotlin, the return@label syntax is used for specifying which
>   function among several nested ones this statement returns from.

Comment: or you can  just remove `return` altogether as mentioned in one of the comment