# Convert Java to Kotlin BiFunction containing code

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, rx-java2

I am trying to convert my Java class into Kotlin.
This is the Java code:

```java
Observable.just("Stacey")
    .zipWith(Observable.just(6),
    (name, age) -> {
        String text;
        if(age < 18){
            text = name + " is a child";
        }else{
            text = name + "is not a child";
        }
        return text;
    }
);
```

And this is what I converted it into:

```
Observable.just("Stacey")
.zipWith(Observable.just(6),
    BiFunction<String, Int, String> {name, age ->
        var text: String
        if(age < 18){
            text = "$name + is a child"
        }else{
            text = "$name + is not a child"
        }
        return text
    }
)
```

Lambda notation does not seem to work at all or I just cannot figure it out. All examples for BiFunctions in Kotlin that I found return a value directly like this

> BiFunction {name, age -> name+age}

which is syntactically correct but I need some additional logic before I return something.
Two error messages appear:

- 'return' is not allowed here
- Type mismatch. Required: Unit, Found: String

But I do want to return a string and I also explicitly declared it. But where else is there to put the return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem once too, all you have to do is to replace 
return text with
return@BiFunction text

For explanations, you can have a look here:

[Kotlin: Whats does "return@" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean)

https://tutorialwing.com/labeled-return-or-return-in-kotlin-with-example

Comment: @Yobuligo you can find more details in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) too