# How to Animate marker position in Mapbox android SDK?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

there is no example code on the website.I found `[old version in java](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/legacy/maps/examples/animate-marker-position/)` but it is too old.

I want to know how to use kotlin and sdk v10.9.1 to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow fused location in your code. Please check [Unable to get current (real time) location using FusedLocationProviderClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587652/unable-to-get-current-real-time-location-using-fusedlocationproviderclient/72595039#72595039) this can help you some way.